# Using same logger and log files across multiple class instances? Problems/Conflicts?

Tags: python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I have 3 classes as follows:

Class1 --> Uses SameClassA --> Uses SameClassB

Class2 --> Uses SameClassA --> Uses SameClassB

The inherited/implement classes denoted as "Class1" and "Class2" make use of the same classes "SameClassA" and "SameClassB", which are not inherited/implemented.

In each of these classes, I am making use of the same initLogger() function. The implementation of the initLogger() function (logger name, logger files etc.) is different for "Class1" and "Class2"; however, it is the same for "SameClassA" and "SameClassB" (same logger name, same logger files etc.).

I noticed there was an error that occurred in my initLogger() function when instantiating "SameClassA" at a time where multiple "SameClassA"s were already instantiated. Unfortunately, since there wasn't a logger, I do not have the stack trace.

**However, what I would like to know, is that does this configuration cause a problem, and what can I do to solve it?**

Here is my initLogger function:

```
    def initLogger(self, infoLog=True, debugLog=True, consoleLog=True):
    try: 
        parentLogDir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'UniversalThreadLogs')
        if not os.path.exists(parentLogDir):
            os.mkdir(parentLogDir)
        infoLogDir = os.path.join(parentLogDir, 'INFOLog')
        if not os.path.exists(infoLogDir):
            os.mkdir(infoLogDir)
        errorLogDir = os.path.join(parentLogDir, "ERRORLog")
        if not os.path.exists(errorLogDir):
            os.mkdir(errorLogDir)

        infoLogFilepath = os.path.join(infoLogDir, "UTInfoLog.log")
        debugLogFilepath = os.path.join(errorLogDir, "UTErrorLog.log")

        LOG_FORMAT = ("%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d")

        debugHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename=debugLogFilepath,maxBytes=5000000, backupCount=100)
        debugHandler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
        debugHandler.setFormatter(Formatter(LOG_FORMAT))

        infoHandler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(filename=infoLogFilepath,maxBytes=5000000, backupCount=100)
        infoHandler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        infoHandler.setFormatter(Formatter(LOG_FORMAT))

        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        stream_handler.setFormatter(Formatter(LOG_FORMAT))

        UTLogger = logging.getLogger("UThread")
        if infoLog is True: 
            UTLogger.addHandler(infoHandler)
        if debugLog is True: 
            UTLogger.addHandler(debugHandler)
        if consoleLog is True: 
            UTLogger.addHandler(stream_handler)
        return UTLogger
    except: 
        return False
```

As mentioned, for "SameClassA" and "SameClassB" the above initLogger() implementation is the same for the respective class, with the same files/directories and the same logger name "UThread", for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to initialise logging once. Call `initLogger()` as a standalone method once at the start of your program, then in each class get a refrence to the logger.

```py
import logging


def init_logging(infoLog=True, debugLog=True, consoleLog=True):
    # what you currently have

    # this is just to create a working demo
    logging.basicConfig(
        format="%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s in %(pathname)s:%(lineno)d",
        level=logging.DEBUG,
    )


class ClassA:
    log = logging.getLogger("UThread")

    def say_hello(self):
        self.log.info("hello from class A")
        class_b = ClassB()
        class_b.say_hello()


class ClassB:
    log = logging.getLogger("UThread")

    def say_hello(self):
        self.log.info("hello from class B")


init_logging()
class_a = ClassA()
class_a.say_hello()
```

This would oputput

```
2020-05-07 18:29:19,642 [INFO]: hello from class A in test.py:16
2020-05-07 18:29:19,642 [INFO]: hello from class B in test.py:25
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think it is definitely the right way to implement. 

However, I would still be curious if this would cause a conflict situation that would result in an error. Just in general, the Python Legality of this.

Comment: This is how [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logger-objects) is designed to work. It's safe to call `logging.getLogger(...)` anywhere in your code. In most cases you only need to configure logging once.

Comment: Fair enough. Your method is the better approach no doubt. 

How about FileHandlers and loggers sharing the same log file?